# Damas-Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, type-inference, hindley-milner

I'm looking for information about the well-known [Damas-Hindley-Milner algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system)
to do type inference for functional languages, especially information about implementation.

I already know how to do the [Algorithm W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Algorithm_W), but I heard about recent new algorithms based on constraint generator/solver rather than usual unification. However, I can't manage to find any discussions about the implementation of those new algorithm.

Any idea where I could find some partial information on ML inference ?

Comment: Are you sure that constraint generation/solving was not for type systems with subtyping, e.g. one of the HM(X) family (Hindley-Milner parameterized by a subtyping relation)?

Comment: I read it could be used for the HM(X) family with subtyping, but also for things like type classes (parametric polymorphism), so I'm a bit puzzled

Comment: Type classes are somewhat orthogonal to parametric polymorphism.  I think Pascal Cuoq might be correct.  I'm not sure I've seen any serious alternatives to plain ol' constraint generation-and-unification for type reconstruction in Standard ML, for example.  Alternative approaches would certainly become useful for the kinds of extensions that have been proposed though.

Comment: Not a 100% answer since you asked about ML, but I wonder if this is what you had heard about: Compositional Type Checking for Hindley-Milner Type Systems with Ad-hoc Polymorphism, Dr. Gerg˝o Érdi https://gergo.erdi.hu/projects/tandoori/Tandoori-Compositional-Typeclass.pdf . As you might guess from the occurrence of the word "typeclass" this is about Haskell.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're comfortable with ML code, the best way to find these things is to simply look into the implementations in the wild.  A good reference implementation is [HaMLet](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/hamlet/), which is designed as more of a test platform rather than a production implementation.

Almost all serious recent discussion of these issues is going to be in scholarly venues.  One paper that might be of interest is [Generalising Hindley-Milner type inference algorithms](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.18.9348&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Also, the implementations of various type systems (including let polymorphism) in Pierce's "[Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/)", as well as Appel's "[Modern Compiler Implementation in ML](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/ml/)" more closely match modern approaches to implementing this than the vanilla description of algorithm W.

Comment: thanks for the ref to HaMLet, I didn't know such project existed !

Comment: @Vinz, yep, it's pretty neat.  It's tied up with some of the (seemingly defunct) work on successor ML.

Comment: I ran across this the other day - it relates Constraint Handling Rules with type inference with Type Classes: http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0006034