# Function type inference with recursive calls

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm trying to implement a custom language that allows function return type to be inferred from its last statement. However, when a direct or indirect recursive function call is found, the type inference system obviously fails.

```
func factorial(a:int) -> 
    if a == 0
        1
    else
        a * factorial(a - 1)
```

For example, F# does this even with argument types unspecified:

```
let rec fact i =
    if i = 0 then 1 else i * fact (i-1)
```

How does this system work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

F# type checker uses [Damas-Hindley-Milner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner) type inference algorithm. The factorial example can be explained roughly as follows:

- From declaration of `fact`, we have its type in the form `tx -> ty` and `tx = t(i)` where `t(i)` is type of a value `i`.
- From the equality check, because of `val (=): 'T -> 'T -> bool` we also have `t(i) = t(0) = int`.
- From `then` branch, we get another constraint `ty = t(1) = int`.
- From `else` branch, the normal `(*)` operator is `'T -> 'T -> 'T` so we get `t(i) = ty`.

Based on the set of constraints:

```
tx = t(i)
t(i) = t(0) = int
ty = t(1) = int
t(i) = ty
```

using unification, we arrive at `tx = ty = int` and infer type of `fact` as `int -> int`. It also means that if you change the order of clauses in `if/then/else` (by reversing conditions), type inference still works fine.

That said, this is a very simple example of the type inference algorithm. 
You can follow the Wikipedia link above to read more about it.

In order to apply the algorithm to your custom language, you can find an implementation in various functional programming books. Please see this thread [Damas-Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641967/damas-hindley-milner-type-inference-algorithm-implementation) for more details.

Comment: For example implementations of type systems, there's [Hindley Milner Type Inference in F#](http://fsharpcode.blogspot.com/2010/08/hindley-milner-type-inference-sample.html) and my [F# port of Types and Programming Languages](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tapl).

Comment: Just saw this answer today. The time zone I'm in, it's 20-3-2013 now,  exactly three years after Robin Milner left the same day.

Comment: @KenKin: We lost a great researcher. I admire him very much for his seminal work.